# How to convert req.files.resume.data to createReadStream in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am uploading *.mp4/mov* file using express-uploader, in my api call i received req.files.resume object which is having `[data]` value like `< Buffer 00 98 09 99 88 77 66 ... >` of type **object**.

I have tried so many thing but not able to convert that object to pass into `fs.createReadStream()`, here's my code

```
router.post('/update-resume', authUtil.ensureAuthenticated, 
 function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.files){
      res.status(400).json({message: "No file"});
    } else if(req.files.resume){
    const resume = req.files.resume;
    if(resume.mimetype === "video/mp4" || resume.mimetype === "video/quicktime"){

    // Create the streams
    var read = 
    fs.createReadStream(Buffer.from(resume.data.toString())); //this is giving error of TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]

    }
  }
});
```

got stuck with this, If anyone can help me!
I am using this code as aws lambda function with api gateway, to upload large file to s3 bucket.

Comment: Since `resume.data` is already a `Buffer` instance, and `fs.createReadStream` should accept such an argument, doesn't it work if you simply call `fs.createReadStream(resume.data);`?

Comment: Nope, that doesn’t worked